The Software & Updates GUI tool does not change the mirror server in /etc/apt/sources.list anymore
The Software & Updates GUI tool does not seem to reflect in /etc/apt/sources.list the new mirror server selected.
I tried both with my user, and with root.
For instance, choosing us.example.com and doing reload (or # apt update),
# grep '^deb' /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.oldexampleiwanttochange.com/Linux/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
... <all like that> ...

It used to work though. But I can't see what causes this problem...

Please add to the question with the edit feature of the question when and how it used to work.
